# How to handle special characters in query strings?

Tags: oracle11g

I am writing a query like

```
select * from fact_table where name = 'R&D'

select * from fact_table where name = 'John's'
```

I am using oracle 11g database. Is there any generic function or query style where in I can handle special characters like '&' and ''' in my query.

I do not want to handle each case seperately, i want a generic mechanism.

If this is a duplicate post please guide me to the original post

Comment: I don't know the "best" way but it seems you could use an escape user defined function to modify your string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Quote Operator

```
select * from fact_table where name = q'#John's#'
```

For ampersands, it is an issue for tools like SQL*Plus

```
set define ~
select * from fact_table where name = 'R&D'
```

But in a pl/sql block, it seems working fine:

```
declare
    output VARCHAR2(10);
BEGIN
    SELECT name 
     INTO output
     FROM fact_table 
    WHERE name = '&1'; 

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Output: ' || output);
END;
/

SQL> @test.sql;
Enter value for 1: R&D
old   7:         WHERE name = '&1';
new   7:         WHERE name = 'R&D';
Output: R&D

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Answer (score 1):

The ampersand should work fine.  Some tools, like SQLPlus or SQLDeveloper use this character to indicate a bind variable.  Disable this "feature" like this:
set define off
re-enable it like this:
set define on

the single quote needs special attention.
Use two single quote characters to tell the database to treat it as a literal, like this:
select * from fact_table where name = 'John''s'